# In Python, how to test whether a line is the last one?

Tags: python

Suppose I want to process each line of a file, but the last line needs special treatment:

```
with open('my_file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if <line is the last line>:
            handle_last_line(line)
        else:
            handle_line(line)
```

The question is, how does one implement ? There seems to be no function for detecting end-of-file in Python.

Is there another solution than read the lines into a list (with f.readlines() or similar)?

Answer (score 15):

Process the **previous** line:

```
with open('my_file.txt') as f:
    line = None
    previous = next(f, None)
    for line in f:
        handle_line(previous)
        previous = line

    if previous is not None:
        handle_last_line(previous)
```

When the loop terminates, you know that the last line was just read.

A generic version, letting you process the N last lines separately, use a [`collections.deque()` object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque):

```
from collections import deque
from itertools import islice

with open('my_file.txt') as f:
    prev = deque(islice(f, n), n)
    for line in f:
        handle_line(prev.popleft())
        prev.append(line)

    for remaining in prev:
        handle_last_line(remaining)
```

Comment: Might it be worth nesting that into the `for`'s `else` for readability?

Comment: More generally, you can use a queue to implement a processing delay of any size.

Comment: @AdamBurry It's easier to use `itertools.tee` as I show in my answer.

Comment: @Josh: The `else:` suite with a `for` loop should only really be used when you use `break` in the loop; it is called *always* otherwise (even if the loop iterable was empty). I personally find that using `else` here would not improve readability.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Fair enough, just my 2¢ :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`itertools.tee`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) to iterate on two copies of an iterable:

```
next_lines, lines = itertools.tee(file_object)
next(next_lines)
for next_line, line in zip(next_lines, lines):
    handle_line(line)
last_line = next(lines, None)
if last_line is not None:
    handle_last_line(last_line)
```

Comment: Your last line handling could be simpler; just do `for last_line in lines: handle_last_line(last_line)`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'd argue that, even though it's shorter, it isn't more readable. It may not be obvious that the `for` loop can be executed at most once. Surely it allows generalization as in your example with `deque`.