# Forkable iterator - is there any implementations of it in Python?

Tags: python, sockets, data-structures, stream, iterator

What I mean by "forkable iterator" - it is a regular iterator with method `fork()` which creates a new iterator which iterates from the current point of iteration of original iterator. And even if the original iterator was iterated further, fork will stay at the point where it was forked, until it itself will not be iterated over.

My practical use case:
I have a socket connection, and some "packets" that sent through it. Connection can be shared between "receivers" and each "packet" can be addressed to some "receiver". "Packets" can come in unordered way, so each "receiver" can potentially receive packet for different "recevier". And more than that - if one "receiver" received "packet" for different "recevier", this "different receiver" must still be able to read that packet.

So for that I want to implement such forkable iterator, which will represent the connection, and each receiver will make own fork, read it and search for "packets" addressed for it.

Does somebody know any implementations of what I'm talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats my current implementation of forkable iterator:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding=utf-8
from collections import Iterator, deque
import threading


class ForkableIterator(Iterator):
    def __init__(self, iterator, buffer=None, *args, **kwargs):
        self.iterator = iter(iterator)
        if buffer is None:
            self.buffer = deque()
        else:
            self.buffer = buffer

        args = iter(args)

        self.refs = kwargs.get('refs', next(args, {}))
        self.refs.setdefault('base', 0)
        self.pointer = kwargs.get('pointer', next(args, 0))
        self.lock = kwargs.get('lock', next(args, threading.Lock()))

    @property
    def pointer(self):
        return self.refs[self] + self.refs['base']

    @pointer.setter
    def pointer(self, value):
        self.refs[self] = value

    def __del__(self):
        del self.refs[self]

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        with self.lock:
            if len(self.buffer) - self.pointer == 0:
                elem = next(self.iterator)
                self.buffer.append(elem)
            else:
                if self.pointer == min(self.refs.itervalues()):
                    elem = self.buffer.popleft()
                    self.refs['base'] -= 1
                else:
                    elem = self.buffer[self.pointer]

            self.pointer += 1

            return elem

    def fork(self):
        return self.__class__(self.iterator, self.buffer,
                              refs=self.refs, pointer=self.pointer,
                              lock=self.lock)
```

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for the [`itertools.tee()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee):

> Return *n* independent iterators from a single iterable.

Do take into account that the implementation will buffer data to service all child iterators:

> This itertool may require significant auxiliary storage (depending on how much temporary data needs to be stored).

Also, you should only use the returned child iterators; iterating over the source iterator will not propagate the data to the `tee()` iterables.

Comment: Wow, I didn't noticed that function before, though I used `itertools` a lot. I think there is possible better implementation than `tee`. `tee` has 3 minuses - 1) It uses multiple lists for temporary data, while it is obvious, that one would be sufficient. 2) With `tee` you can not fork an another fork (see [link](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a56e5bbcb64a108acb68)). 3) It would be valuable to have option to use custom container as buffer - for example it can be something like `DiskCachedList` - for large amount for temporary data.

Comment: @GillBates 1) the documentation Python implementation is an illustration; the [actual implementation](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/14a69e40dbb0/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c#l317) does not use separate queues 2) you are creating more children then advancing a parent which the documentation specifically prohibits 3) you are free to implement your own specialised versions. In my opinion there are better ways to optimize algorithms than using tee with a disk cache.

Comment: 3) What are they? For example - for my use case (see main text) 2) Docs says nothing about double-forking.

Comment: @GillBates: 3) it depends on the problem you are trying to solve. Example: I [used a `deque` to track n last lines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18449646/in-python-how-to-test-whether-a-line-is-the-last-one), while a `tee` was used in the other answer. Your case isn't concrete enough to say anything, really. 2) Yes they do: *Once `tee()` has made a split, the original iterable should not be used anywhere else*.

Comment: 2) I'm talking about calling `tee` on one of the iterators that was obtained from another `tee` call.

Comment: @GillBates: the `tee()` call doesn't care where the iterator came from, it doesn't special case `tee()` iterators when passed in, it is *just another parent iterator*. You cannot use that parent iterator.